# How to stop sound for Java game

Tags: java, audio

So I have this class that plays background music in my java game on netbeans. I just want some ideas on how I could stop the sound if my character dies. I tried making a public boolean isCollided variable but for whenever my character collides with another object but it didn't work. I am open to suggestions.

```
import controller.Main;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public static boolean isCollided = false;

public static void play(String filename) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Main.class.getResourceAsStream(filename)));// new
                                                                                                        // File(filename)));
                if (isCollided) {
                    clip.stop();
                } else {
                    clip.loop(0);
                }
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: How is it that you have a static method accessing a non-static member variable? Also, you are missing a semi-colon. Please post code that at least compiles and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I am sorry I am having to type it by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using

```
clip.stop();
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#stop()

I see you made some edits.  Since you are running the clip in a thread, you'd need to have some way of interacting with the thread from your main method.  Otherwise it just checks isCollided when the thread starts and never checks for changes.

One way would be to make isCollided a global variable and then have an infinite loop in the clip thread that checks for isCollided and stops when it becomes true.  Something (with your variables) like

```
while (true) {
  if (isCollided) {
  clip.stop();
  thread.interupt();
  }
}
```

ETA: This is very processor intensive.  You maybe could add a little delay like

```
while (true) {
  Thread.sleep(500);
  if (isCollided) {
  clip.stop();
  thread.interupt();
  }
}
```

to keep it from bogging down your processor too much.

Comment: Yeah I updated my code. I think the clip.stop() method does work. Its just that my isCollided variable didn't get updated. I put System.out.println(isCollided) and it only printed once. So im assuming when I collide, the isCollided variable does not get updated. Thus it is always false.

Comment: @Marco Java is pass by value. Check out this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647969/change-boolean

Comment: It is usually not a good idea to interrupt a thread. It would be better to build in a mechanism to allow the thread to finish execution cleanly.

Comment: When I use thread.interupt(). I get an error message. I just removed it and it worked. So what was the thread.interupt() meant for? Better performance?

Comment: If you want to use `Thread.sleep(500);` don't forget to `throw` or `try-catch` the `InterruptedException`.

Comment: Ok I'll be sure to do that. Thanks @StarCoder

Comment: @Marco No problem.