# Can't reset list after change

Tags: java

I have 10 elements List with 1 true and 9 false.

I want change last element for true and set rest to false.
I dont know why my code no works, in debug mode I set all for false, but in console i see 2x true.

My code is probably wrong:

```
public class Test {

    private static boolean a = true;
    private static boolean b;
    private static boolean c;
    private static boolean d;
    private static boolean e;

    private static boolean a2;
    private static boolean b2;
    private static boolean c2;
    private static boolean d2;
    private static boolean e2;

    private static List<Boolean> listOfBooleans = new LinkedList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        listOfBooleans.add(a);
        listOfBooleans.add(b);
        listOfBooleans.add(c);
        listOfBooleans.add(d);
        listOfBooleans.add(e);
        listOfBooleans.add(a2);
        listOfBooleans.add(b2);
        listOfBooleans.add(c2);
        listOfBooleans.add(d2);
        listOfBooleans.add(e2);

        for (Boolean listOfBoolean : listOfBooleans) {
            System.out.println(listOfBoolean);
        }

        System.out.println("\n");

        setOnlyOne(9);

        for (Boolean listOfBoolean : listOfBooleans) {
            System.out.println(listOfBoolean);
        }

    }

    private static void setOnlyOne(int index){
        for (Boolean listOfBoolean : listOfBooleans) {
            listOfBoolean = false;
        }
        listOfBooleans.set(index, true);
    }

}
```

What I should change here ?

Comment: In setOnlyOne, listOfBooleans will be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with `for-each` loop in `setOnlyOne` method. It is looping through all elements of `ArrayList` but not updating the value of the list. Instead, it is updating local value that we get using `for-each` construct and updating it to `false`. Doing this has no impact on `ArrayList` object.

So, instead of using for-each loop, you normal for loop and use `set` method of ArrayList to update individual element. Try below code

```
private static void setOnlyOne(int index) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfBooleans.size(); i++) {
        listOfBooleans.set(i, false);
    }
    listOfBooleans.set(index, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
private static void setOnlyOne(int index){
        for (Boolean listOfBoolean : listOfBooleans) {
            listOfBoolean = false;
        }
        listOfBooleans.set(index, true);
    }
```

you do not set `false` value to elements of listOfBooleans list. 
You only set local value to false. 
Try to alter your code:

```
 private static void setOnlyOne(int index){
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfBooleans.size(); i++) {
            listOfBooleans.set(i, false);
        }
        listOfBooleans.set(index, true);
    }
```

Btw. calling single value from list `listOfBoolean` is misleading because it is not a list in your case. It's just a single element.
Name it `singleBoolean` or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean is immutable object like string. So changing it's value to false will not gonna change the value in list. It is creating new object when you are changing it to false.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647969/change-boolean-values

Comment: Although you're right that Boolean is immutable it doesn't matter in this case here. The effect here and in your linked question is caused by Java being "pass by value". The same would happen if you would use a mutable type (or a primitive type), instead of Boolean or String.

Comment: You can change value of mutable object in for each loop. Try this   import java.util.*;
public class test {
public static void main(String args[]){

StringBuilder a1 = new StringBuilder("a1");

StringBuilder a2 = new StringBuilder("a2");
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add(a1);
list.add(a2);

for(Object c : list)
{
 StringBuilder sb = (StringBuilder) c;
 if(sb.toString().equals("a1"))
 sb.append("test");
}
System.out.println(list);
}}

Comment: **"You can change value of mutable object in for each loop."** No you can't and your posted code snippet doesn't do that either. You need to mind the difference between assigning an object reference to a variable (which is the case in this question) and _mutating_ an object (what your posted code does). These are different things and have different rules.

Comment: Thanks got it. I was thinking about only modifying object.